# Where are all of the ingredients for Makena's spice recipe?

Tags: the-journey-down-chapter1

At one point, Mama Makena asks you to help her collect a bunch of different ingredients for her special spice mix.

- Chilies
- Extra Virgin Olive Oil
- Lemon
- Chervil
- Salt
- Ginger

Only problem is, I have no idea where to find some of these.  Reading a full walkthrough will spoil the entire game for me, so I'd rather not if I can avoid it.  Anyone know where these are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer on this guide:

http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcJj/JourneyDown/JourneyDown.htm

Since you don't want spoilers, here's the bit that's relevant to your question:

> **Chilies:**    Combine the chilies taken from the sailors with the spice
>   container.
>
> **Extra virgin oil:**    Go back to the pier left of the plane. Use the
>   spice container on the oil tap.
>
> **Lemon:**    Enter the Charter office. Check the blue cup on the counter
>   to get lemon added in with the mix.
>
> **Chervil:**    Go up the ladder and check the books on the bookshelf.
>   Bwana finds chervil and adds it to the mix.
>
> **Salt:**    Go to the ship. Go right of the ship where the pelican and
>   the forklift is located. Get salt from the box left of the forklift. Bwana adds it to the mix.
>
> **Ginger:**  Enter the ship and climb the ladder to go to the yacht.